# Proposal to remove the [tag:working-visas] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We generally close work visas as off-topic, apart from [working-holiday](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-holiday) questions.

However it must be a bit confusing for people since we do have a [work-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-visas) tag.  It's tagged on 14 questions, most closed or off-topic.

I propose removing the tag, to prevent the risk of work visa questions coming up.

However, it's entirely possible there's a use case I've not considered.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe people who want to ask whether they can use their work visa from country A to travel to country B. As in 'can I use my French national visa to travel to other Schengen countries?'. But I think this is rather marginal and support deleting the tag as it is rather confusing indeed.

Comment: Perhaps we can come up with another tag for that use case.

Comment: I'm not convinced. It won't have any effect on people posting off-topic question. My question about whether you can work in Georgia on a tourist visa could just as easily have been "or would you require a work visa"? That would be on topic and so would other questions. You mentioned *most* were closed or off-topic, now tell us about the others, since it seems like you looked through them one by one. All this said I am open to being convinced in either direction. We already have the plain old umbrella tag [tag:visas] after all.

Comment: Don't we already have a business visas tag? Business visas and work visas are different. Well conceptually. In reality some countries such as USA treat them the same and some countries don't.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion:  it's not so much keeping users from opening off-topic questions as it is the potential of "you have a tag called work-visas, so they must be/are allowed" or "there exists a work-visas tag, it was allowed to exist, so my question must be allowed to remain"

One of my larger pet peeves is someone asking a question, which has more recently been of a type we've decided is off-topic, but they fight closure by dredging up questions from years ago and say "see? that question was allowed to remain, why is mine being closed"

Answer (score 1):

There may be some confusion about these tags:

[working-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-visas) Usage guide:

> Working visas as they interact with other documents for travel of relatively short duration. Long-term visits to any particular country and prolonged work there may be covered at the Expatriates Stack Exchange site.

Currently in use for 12 Open questions. Seems its existence is justified, though may be being abused.

[working-holiday](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-holiday) Usage guide:

> Travelling and working usually under one of several special arrangements between various countries for people younger than a certain age and lasting not longer than a year or two.

Currently in use for 41 Open questions. I see no particular issue with it.

[work-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-visas)  No usage.

Maybe the question should be changed to *Proposal to remove the [work-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-visas) tag?* and, as that tag effectively no longer exists, the fact recorded and an answer to that effect accepted.