# Can we please get tags to show in question headings on meta?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

As seen in [this question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3424/proposal-to-remove-the-tagworking-visas-tag), despite the use of

> `[tag:work-visas]`

it's not converting to the cool [work-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-visas) like it does in the body.

Can we fix this, or is there some reason not to?

Answer (score 1):

`[tag:tag-name]` is considered to be markdown. Similar requests have already been made and [declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285727/allow-markdown-in-question-titles) in [the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237125/can-we-get-markdown-support-in-questions-title-field).

Please check http://meta.stackexchange.com before writing [feature-request](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) that would affect the entire network.